# How to apply css to existing class?

Tags: html, css

We are trying to add CSS for the below html:-

```
<div class="main">
        <div class="main-content">
        <a href="...">
            <img src="">
        </a>
        <h2 class="main-heading">
            <a href="">2022</a>
        </h2>
        <div class="main-description">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </div>
        <div class="main-link">
            <a>Test Data</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In our case , when we are using the above html and apply this CSS the it is showing the margin correct :-

```
.main>.main-content .main-description {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

However, In some cases we are removing `.main-description` div then it is not showing the padding and margin after it. We need to manage like this we have all the above html and may we in some case we don't have `main-description` and `main-heading`. Is it possible to apply CSS if we don't have particular div then apply and when we have particular div then don't apply without jQuery.

Case 1:
without description :-

```
  <div class="main">
            <div class="main-content">
            <a href="...">
                <img src="">
            </a>
            <h2 class="main-heading">
                <a href="">2022</a>
            </h2>
            
            <div class="main-link">
                <a>Test Data</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In this case when we don't have `main-description` then `main-link` will attach with `main-heading`. We don't want add extra padding or margin for `main-heading` as when we have full html then it will create a extra padding or margin.

Case 2: -
Without heading:-

```
<div class="main">
            <div class="main-content">
            <a href="...">
                <img src="">
            </a>
            <div class="main-description">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </div>
            <div class="main-link">
                <a>Test Data</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In this case without `main-heading`. Same scenario for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Updated to fit your new requirement: Use the `+` selector to select an element which comes after another.

```
.main-heading + .main-link {
    /* This matches if main-link directly follows main heading, with no element inbetween */
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Maybe instead of specifying all these margins and paddings you can just use flexbox and set a `gap` property, so all elements have a default spacing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have updated my question. In some case we dont have `main-description ` div then we need some padding after `main-heading`. If we provide it when we have `main-description ` then it will add extra padding there. So we would like to get a solution when we dont have `main-description ` then some css apply. When we have `main-description ` then it does not apply.